# How to add Flash Player prebuilt application to the system.img in android?

Tags: build-process, apk, android-source, flash-player-11

I am trying to customize my android system by adding Flash Player to the default system applications.
I added the .apk file to packages/apps/FlashPlayer, with the Android.mk file

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_MODULE := FlashPlayer
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := FlashPlayer.apk
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := .apk
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := APPS
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := PRESIGNED
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

This apk also uses some libraries: libflashplayer.so libstagefright_froyo.so. libstagefright_honeycomb.so and libysshared.so.

I created a module for each one and added them to generic.mk in the variable 
PRODUCT_PACKAGES

```
PRODUCT_PACKAGES:=  libflashplayer \
libstagefright_froyo \
libstagefright_honeycomb \
libysshared \
FlashPlayer \
```

I tested with adb shell, the apk is in /system/app and the libs are present in /system/lib
but when I try to play a movie from a browser, it says that the flash player is not installed.

However if I manually install FlashPlayer with adb install command the movie can be played from browser.

Can you help with this issue?

Comment: Update: Extracts from LogCat: 01-02 00:01:57.580: E/dalvikvm(2422): Can't open dex cache '/data/dalvik-cache/system@app@FlashPlayer.apk@classes.dex': No such file or directory
01-02 00:01:57.580: I/dalvikvm(2422): Unable to open or create cache for /system/app/FlashPlayer.apk (/data/dalvik-cache/system@app@FlashPlayer.apk@classes.dex)
01-02 00:01:57.590: E/PluginManager(2422): Can't find plugin's class: com.adobe.flashplayer.FlashPaintSurface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Libs should be in /system/lib/plugins/com.adobe.flashplayer, according to PluginManager.java.

Answer (score 0):

I got the very same problem. For some reason, WebKit is unable to load plugins that are installed by adding them into PRODUCT_PACKAGES list. However, WebKit will load them if you install them with adb install. I still did not find other way for installing them. Only adb install will make them work. Please, update your post here if You got any progress on this.